# Delegate does not take 1 arguments

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a simple Where clause that filters through a small container class like this:

```
var _cDetail = _cDetails.Where(c => Convert.ToString(c.ServiceProductId) == _cNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

And I have it defined in another project (but included in the other project's references with a "using" statement referring to that project) as a simple class that looks like this:

```
public class CDetail
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceProductId { get; set; }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Delegate 'System.Func<OtherClass.CDetail,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
```

I see this one in google a lot, but my circumstances seem a lot different.

Where does the obj,int,bool even come from?

Comment: What is the type of `_cDetails`

Comment: How you have defined `_cDetail` ?

Comment: The error isn't present in the code you've supplied. Can you give the actual line the error occurred on?

Comment: @CoryNelson: The single line up above (with the Where clause) is that line that gets the error.

Comment: @Habib: _cDetail is of type CDetail

Comment: @JaredPar: _cDetails is of type List<CDetail>.

Comment: @micahhoover, I meant `cDetails`, but your reply to JaredPar, cleared it. I am not sure your current code would have this error. Are you sure you are getting the error on this line ?

Comment: Rather than the where clause, you can use the delegate in the FirstOrDefault statement.  If you try that, see if you get the same error occurring.

Comment: Also, rather than converting your int to a string, why not convert cNumber to an int first.  That way you avoid multiple converts.

Comment: @stevethethread: Changed to FirstOrDefault and it barked about nothing being able to figure out what type the var should be. Surprising because I would think FirstOrDefault() would involve the same parameters as Where(). It isn't able to resolve the type appears to be the problem. Well, one less iterator to deal with. Thanks !

Comment: I have just emulated your code in  LinqPad, and it seems to run just fine.  What is _cDetails?  Is it a list of CDetail?. How is the data populated etc.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio couldn't find where the type of this object (CDetail) was declared.

Instead of saying something like, "CDetail is not declared in this context" or something like that, it sent me on a wild goose chase.

I am keeping this question up in case someone else comes across this problem.

Thanks to everyone for the help.